# $x^2-xy+y^2=n$ how many solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I want to know how many solutions $x^2-xy+y^2=n$ depending on n. I know that it is a norm in ring of Eisenstein integers and so I should find how many integers have norm n. Also I know that this number is finite and is equal to $6k$ $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280551/primes-congruent-to-1-mod-6?noredirect=1&lq=1)  together with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148152/is-it-true-that-a2-abb2c2-cdd2-h2-hkk2-for-some-coprime-h-and#comment6484697_3148152). . This answers the question. So, for example, how many solutions do we have for $n=5$?

Comment: It seems that there are no solutions

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A004016](https://oeis.org/A004016) enumerates the solutions. The entry has much information you may want to know and use.